# visjs.org library trouble

Tags: cluster-analysis, vis.js

I just arrive to my new job and my boss told me that I had to work with visjs.org library for graphos.

I have to work with "19_scale_free_graph_clustering" example. The groups that has >=10 nodes have to change of color. 
This library is so rare, the code has so much declarations that still I can't understand it. I just can change the color of all nodes but it is not the problem, I need change the groups that has >= 10 nodes in his cluster. Can someone understand me? Help me please. 
Still I can't do it in 4 days, can someone help me please?

Here a snippet of the code, I don't know if I'm doing in the right part. This library has 30.000 lines of codes with so much declarations. This is a network little part that is where I'm working.

```
for (nodeId in this.nodes) {
      if (this.nodes.hasOwnProperty(nodeId)) {
        var node = this.nodes[nodeId];
        if (node.clusterSize > 1) {
          //node.label = "[".concat(String(node.clusterSize),"]"); De esta manera se muestra el numero del nodo entre llaves
            node.label = "".concat(String(node.clusterSize),"");
            if(node.clusterSize >= 10){
                this.defaultOptions.nodes.color.background = "#fff";// Here Im changing the color to all nodes
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: If you show the code and the output you're having trouble with you'll get more helpful responses.

Comment: Thanks, I just posted a snippet of network part.